# Document Version on Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

I use createfolder or streamupdate , the problems is , thats version twice , i mean  every upload  alfresco do:

call to uploadFile....
back to document version
version  0.2
version  0 1

again..
call to uploadFile....
back to document version

version 0.4
version 0.3

.... how can i do to versión just one versión for uploadfile?

Here is the code for Create Document and Update Document.

Create Document...

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    dis.readFully(bytes);

    Map<String, String> newDocProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    newDocProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
    newDocProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, file.getName());
    newDocProps.put(PropertyIds.IS_LATEST_VERSION, "TRUE");
    List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
    List<Ace> removeAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
    List<Policy> policies = new LinkedList<Policy>();
    try {
        ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(file.getName(),  BigInteger.valueOf(bytes.length), fileType, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        Document doc = folder.createDocument(newDocProps, contentStream, VersioningState.MINOR, policies, removeAces, addAces, session.getDefaultContext());
        AlfrescoDocument alfDoc = (AlfrescoDocument) doc; 
        if(alfDoc.hasAspect("P:cm:versionable")) { 
          Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
          properties.put("cm:autoVersion", true); 
          alfDoc.updateProperties(properties); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(e.getMessage().contains("Conflict")){
            Document document = (Document) session.getObject(session.getObjectByPath(".../Space/"+file.getName()).getId());
            ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(file.getName(), BigInteger.valueOf(bytes.length), fileType, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            updateDcoument(document,contentStream);             

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: there's no such a thing as uploadFile in OpenCMIS, I guess it's custom code. Can you please post it?

Comment: When I call folder.createDocument(...), It works fine but when I going to check version History on my browser for this document, it saws me 0.1 and 0.2 version. And both version contain same content.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you really create two versions of the document:

```
Document doc = folder.createDocument(newDocProps, contentStream, VersioningState.MINOR, policies, removeAces, addAces, session.getDefaultContext());
```

and

```
alfDoc.updateProperties(properties);
```

As by default `cm:versionable` is set to have `cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps` set to `true` the latter call issues a new version to be created. You can set that property to `false` on the object or globally by altering the `cm:versionable` definition. See the [docs](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Versioning_Behaviour#Configuring_the_Auto-Version_Behaviour_for_Property-Only_Updates_.283.2.29).

Comment: I have delete alfDoc.updateProperties(properties); portion from my code but still have same prob. Should we update version manually of document with code?? I mean Alfresco do version itself.